# Optimization, find the dimensions of the poster with the smallest area

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization

[image: Poster]

The top and bottom margins of a poster are 4 cm and the side margins are each 2 cm. If the area of printed material on the poster is fixed at 380 square centimeters, find the dimensions of the poster with the smallest area.

Refer to the given diagram. Let w be the width (in centimeters) of the poster and let h be the height (in centimeters) of the poster.

What is the width of the printed material, as a function of w?

w-4

What is the height of the printed material, as a function of h?

h-8

Use the fact that the area of the printed material must be fixed at 380 square centimeters to write h as a function of w:

h = 380/(w-4) +8

Write the formula for the area A(w) of the entire poster as a function of w only:

A(w) = ?

Find the critical number c of A(w) which lies in the interval $(4, \infty)$:

c = ?

What are the dimensions of the poster with the smallest area?

w = $\sqrt{190} + 4$

h = $2 \cdot \sqrt{190} +8$

**Attempt at solving**:

The area of the printed region: (h-8) $\cdot$ (w-4) = 380

h = $\frac {380}{w-4} + 8$

The dimensions of the poster are: h, w

Therefore the area of the poster in terms of w is:

A = $(\frac{380}{w - 4} + 8) (w - 4) $

However, my answers for the formula for the area of the poster is incorrect, why?

And what's the correct critical number then?

Comment: Is the answer min, area = 412+36sqrt(95) cm sq. ?

Comment: @gaurav nope....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the dimensions of the poster and the dimensions of the printed material.  The first equation should be $(h-8) \cdot (w-4) = 380$.  I think that is the source of all the errors, your method is correct otherwise.

Comment: I don't get it, it stills says wrong for the area formula, I tried this one: A = (380/w - 8)(w-4). What's wrong?? And why do you assume the sides h and w to be the sides of the poster and not the sides of the printed material?

Comment: oh nevermind, 380/(w-4) +8 is the answer for "write h as a function of w."

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the correct answers to:

Write the formula for the area A(w) of the entire poster as a function of w only:

A(w) = ?

Find the critical number c of A(w) which lies in the interval $(4, \infty)$:

c = ?

Are:

A(w) = $(\frac{380}{w-4} +8) \cdot w$

w = c = $4 + \sqrt{190}$